# DSLR with gphoto2

Tags: raspberrypi, 3d, photography, gphoto2

I'm trying to use my Nikon D3100 DSLR camera to make timelapses of my 3D prints with Octolapse. However, when I send the gphoto2 --capture-image command the camera freezes and it enters in a some kind of never-ending loading state. I'm running gphoto2 2.5.27.1 developer version. Any thoughts/ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How I solved it:
https://www.reddit.com/r/octoprint/comments/o9j3y3/gphoto2_with_octoprintoctolapse/
Basically, you need to change your usb cable, format the sd card and try an earlier version of gphoto2.